# ssh script asks for password

Tags: bash, ssh

a little ssh issue here.

I set up some keys in ssh between 2 machines and I can login via ssh without password in terminal.

I am trying to write a shell script that sends commands to the remote server through ssh. When i run the script it always asks for the ssh password before performing the commands. How can I make it so the ssh login in the script is passwordless like it is through terminal?

in the script it's like ssh user@remoteMachine 'do some stuff'
the same command in terminal works perfectly fine.

(edit) verbose flag differences

script:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/remote/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/remote/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/remote/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@192.168.1.4's password:
```

terminal

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/remote/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.4 ([192.168.1.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i686)
```

the script is just

```
#/usr/bin/bash

ssh user@192.168.1.4 'touch ~/test'
```

I am making the script executable and calling it with

```
./script
```

Comment: You're running the script by hand in the same login session? Or you're running it in another session, e.g. with cron?

Comment: Same login session currently

Comment: Try `ssh -v` to print verbose debugging info. What's the difference?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I edited the original posting with the differences.

Comment: Does the script set any environment variables?

Comment: None, i have everything commented out except the ssh user@192.168.1.4 'touch ~/test'

Comment: give output of `ssh -v user@192.168.1.4 'touch ~/test'` in terminal

Comment: Maybe you can post the script, the command to call the script and the command used in terminal?

Comment: On the command line run: `ssh user@192.168.1.4 'touch ~/test'`, `bash`, `ssh user@192.168.1.4 'touch ~/test'`, `exit`, `. ./script` and `./script` and post the output.

Comment: And are you using `ssh-agent` or an empty passphrase?

Comment: try using: ssh-add .ssh/keyname. Then run the script. Do you still need a password?

Comment: The first line of the script should be `#!/bin/bash` ([shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))), but this wouldn't cause your problem. Do you have an alias for `ssh`? What is the output of `type ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `sshpass` package on you machine and after that
For running commands remotely:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT='
#Your commands
'
sshpass -p<pass> ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> user@host "$SCRIPT"
```

You also have `sshpass -f<file>` and you can use file of passwords for all of your servers...So you can write a loop for making ssh and doing stuff automatically...